# Registering with phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, user-registration

I am working on an app that will require registering (or verifying?) with phone number just like WhatsApp or Telegram or many messaging apps do. Something like this:

[image: hike]
[image: WhatsApp]
[image: Telegram]

Is it possible to do something like that with Parse.com? Or what would be the best option to implement this service?

Thank you!

Comment: What? parse.com is not for free sms or whatever, i don't see what parse.com has to do with your question

Comment: @newboyhun I didn't say free, I use Parse for user registration in other apps, so I was wondering if it could be use with this kind of registration, and it can, Joel mentioned in his answer that Parse partnered with Twilio for this service

Comment: @JoseZamudio there loads of sms provider api on the web, try looking at [nexmo](https://nexmo.com/). they also offer passcoe validation etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be possible with Parse as your backend. You'd need a third party SMS service to send the txt. Parse is partnered with Twilio for sending SMS messages. See [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/send-sms-using-twilio-in-ios-application). There are many other SMS API services available as well if you just google search it.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know what the service was called so I couldn't google it, I will look into the link you sent me!